# core data sql debug = 1 results

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Dear community.
What mean log bellow for good working application? Is it mean any troubles? I seen that everything work fine.

> 2011-02-09 09:43:14.122
>   snow[4316:1a03] CoreData: annotation:
>   to-many relationship fault
>   "codesvsDestinationsList" for objectID
>   0x200b8d740
>   
>   fulfilled from database.  Got 1 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you're being confused by the word 'fault'. It has a very specific meaning in the context of Core Data.

[Here's Apple's documentation on the subject.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)